# Which colours should be chosen to match a metro theme and be easily readable?

Tags: website-design, color

I am colourblind, which makes choosing the colours of my website very hard (often I choose  colours that appeal to me, yet look awful to everyone else). I have recently begun a new website (image below), and I chose these colours for it. Now, to me, it looks really nice, but to everyone else who has seen it, it looks really really really bad.

I am trying to design this website with a metro-ish theme (hence the font, lack of shadows and lack of gradients). I also like the colour blue (hence the blue backgrounds and headings).

**Does anyone know of a good blue colour palette or a website with detailed metro/blue colour scheme tutorials?**

[image: My website]
<sup>*Click on image for full size*</sup>

Comment: I don't really understand how blue, grey, white and black can "look horrible to everyone else." Who is this "everyone"? :)

Comment: @Scott so you are saying it looks fine as it is?

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with that color scheme. It's just one color and grey... it's pretty hard to go wrong with that combination as long as there is enough contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While obviously this is very much a matter of project-specific design, I would suggest a lighter colour, as part of the problems seems to me to be too much contrast, and possibly a blue-er colour, since it is a little purple (probably a result of colour-blindness). Also, the very dark pinstripes look a little too dark. In terms of colours, I tested rgb(21,92,166) on it and it looked pretty good.